# How do I sort a dataframe by an array not in the dataframe

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, numpy

I've answered this question several times in the guise of different contexts and I realized that there isn't a good canonical approach specified anywhere.

So, to set up a simple problem:

## Problem

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(6), B=[1, 2] * 3))
print(df)

   A  B
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  3  2
4  4  1
5  5  2
```

#### Question:

*How do I sort by the product of columns '`A'` and `'B'`**?***
Here is an approach where I add a temporary column to the dataframe, use it to `sort_values` then `drop` it.

```
df.assign(P=df.prod(1)).sort_values('P').drop('P', 1)

   A  B
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
4  4  1
3  3  2
5  5  2
```

---

*Is there a better, more concise, clearer, more consistent approach?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***TL;DR***
`iloc` + `argsort`

---

We can approach this using [**`iloc`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) where we can take an array of ordinal positions and return the dataframe reordered by these positions.

With the power of [**`iloc`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), we can **`sort`** with any array that specifies the order.

Now, all we need to do is identify a method for getting this ordering.  Turns out there is a method called [**`argsort`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) which does exactly this.  By passing the results of [**`argsort`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) to [**`iloc`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), we can get our dataframe sorted out.

## Example 1

*Using the specified problem above*

```
df.iloc[df.prod(1).argsort()]
```

Same results as above

```
   A  B
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
4  4  1
3  3  2
5  5  2
```

That was for simplicity.  We could take this further if performance is an issue and focus on `numpy`

```
v = df.values
a = v.prod(1).argsort()
pd.DataFrame(v[a], df.index[a], df.columns)
```

---

*How fast are these solutions?*

[image]

We can see that `pd_ext_sort` is the most concise but does not scale as well as the others.
`np_ext_sort` gives the best performance at the expense of transparency.  Though, I'd argue that it's still very clear what is going on.

***backtest setup***

```
def add_drop():
    return df.assign(P=df.prod(1)).sort_values('P').drop('P', 1)

def pd_ext_sort():
    return df.iloc[df.prod(1).argsort()]

def np_ext_sort():
    v = df.values
    a = v.prod(1).argsort()
    return pd.DataFrame(v[a], df.index[a], df.columns)

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([10, 100, 1000, 10000], name='Size'),
    columns=pd.Index(['add_drop', 'pd_ext_sort', 'np_ext_sort'], name='method')
)

for i in results.index:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(i, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}()'.format(j)
        setup = 'from __main__ import df, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setup, number=100))

results.plot()
```

## Example 2

Suppose I have a column of negative and positive values.  I want to sort by increasing magnitude... however, I want the negatives to come first.

Suppose I have dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(-2, 3)))
print(df)

   A
0 -2
1 -1
2  0
3  1
4  2
```

I'll set up 3 versions again.  This time I'll use `np.lexsort` which returns the same type of array as `argsort`.  Meaning, I can use it to reorder the dataframe.

***Caveat:*** `np.lexsort` sorts by the last array in its list first.  *\shurg*

```
def add_drop():
    return df.assign(P=df.A >= 0, M=df.A.abs()).sort_values(['P', 'M']).drop(['P', 'M'], 1)

def pd_ext_sort():
    v = df.A.values
    return df.iloc[np.lexsort([np.abs(v), v >= 0])]

def np_ext_sort():
    v = df.A.values
    a = np.lexsort([np.abs(v), v >= 0])
    return pd.DataFrame(v[a, None], df.index[a], df.columns)
```

All of which return

```
   A
1 -1
0 -2
2  0
3  1
4  2
```

*How fast this time?*

[image]

In this example, both `pd_ext_sort` and `np_ext_sort` outperformed `add_drop`.

***backtest setup***

```
results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([10, 100, 1000, 10000], name='Size'),
    columns=pd.Index(['add_drop', 'pd_ext_sort', 'np_ext_sort'], name='method')
)

for i in results.index:
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(i, 1), columns=['A'])
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}()'.format(j)
        setup = 'from __main__ import df, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setup, number=100))

results.plot(figsize=(15, 6))
```