# sort a dataframe based on values of another column, using integer data type

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I want to sort a pandas dataframe based on a column, but the values are stored as strings, but they should be treated as integers.

```
df.sort(col1)
```

where `col1 = ['0','1','12','13','3']`.

How can I use it so that it considers these numbers as integers and not strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep your dataframe untouched and just want to sort it...
This is assuming `col1` is a column in your dataframe `df`

***option 1***

```
df.iloc[df['col1'].astype(int).argsort()]
```

***option 2***
You can also use `pd.to_numeric`

```
df.iloc[pd.to_numeric(df['col1']).argsort()]
```

***option 3***
For more efficiency you can reconstruct manipulating the underlying numpy array

```
v = df.values
a = df['col1'].values.astype(int).argsort()
pd.DataFrame(v[a], df.index[a], df.columns)
```

[**See also**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43195702/2336654)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this before sorting:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(int)
```